# Include nested associations in JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

```
# Person.rb
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
end

# Event.rb
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  has_many :tables
end

# Table.rb
class Table < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
end
```

Within Person.rb I am trying to create a method to get all events and tables in one query

```
def complete_events
  events.includes(:tables)
end
```

I can see in the console it is loading both events and table

```
  Event Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE "event"."person_id" = $1  [["person_id", 17]]
  Table Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "tables".* FROM "tables" WHERE "tables"."event_id" IN (10)
```

However, the returned object is only the event records.

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Event id: 1, name: "some event">]
```

How can I get the returned record to nested like below?

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Event id: 1, name: "some event", tables: [id: 1, seats: 4, id: 2, seats: 4]>]
```

### Edit

I am able to iterate and create a `all_events` object, but it not nested.

```
  def complete_events
    all_events = []
    events.includes(:tables).each do |event|
      all_events << event
      all_events << event.tables
    end
    all_events
  end
```

Comment: Are you looking for JSON output?  You know you can iterate through the `complete_events` relation and accessing tables for events won't call additional queries.

Comment: Yes, JSON is the goal - I am trying to output it all as one JSON nested object. That the trouble I am having.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`as_json`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html):

```
def complete_events
 as_json(
   include: {
     events: {
       include: tables
   }
 )
end
```

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
  User.all.as_json(methods:[:profile,:addresses])
```

here User is the Model, and profile and address are the mapped table having has_many or has_one associations , so the json that will be rendered will be containing the table in nested way as follows

```
user : {
name:"dummy name",
     profile: {},
     addresses: {}
}
```

so in one single object  you will have all the data and the associated data.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.